# Regular Expressions: get what is outside of the brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using PHP and I have text like:

```
first [abc] middle [xyz] last
```

I need to get what's inside and outside of the brackets. Searching in StackOverflow I found a pattern to get what's inside:

```
preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $m, $s)
```

Now I'd like to know the pattern to get what's outside.

Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for this as:

```
$input ='first [abc] middle [xyz] last';
$arr = preg_split('/\[.*?\]/',$input);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first 
    [1] =>  middle 
    [2] =>  last
)
```

This allows some surrounding spaces in the output. If you don't want them you can use:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s*\[.*?\]\s*/',$input);
```

---

`preg_split` splits the string based on a pattern. The pattern here is `[` followed by anything followed by `]`. The regex to match anything is `.*`. Also `[` and `]` are regex meta char used for char class. Since we want to match them literally we need to escape them to get `\[.*\]`. `.*` is by default greedy and will try to match as much as possible. In this case it will match `abc] middle [xyz`. To avoid this we make it non greedy by appending it with a `?` to give `\[.*?\]`. Since our def of anything here actually means anything other than `]` we can also use `\[[^]]*?\]`

**EDIT:**

If you want to extract words that are both inside and outside the `[]`, you can use:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\[|\]/',$input);
```

which split the string on a `[` or a `]`

Comment: this still does not meet the OP requirements ?

Comment: No problem, nice to clean spaces aswell saves using trim, `/\s*\\[|\\]\s*/`

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_split instead of preg_match.

```
preg_split('/\[.*?\]/', 'first [abc] middle [xyz] last');
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "first "
  [1]=>
  string(8) " middle "
  [2]=>
  string(5) " last"
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/hB4Nd)

Answer (score 2):

```
$inside = '\[.+?\]';
$outside = '[^\[\]]+';
$or = '|';

preg_match_all(
    "~ $inside $or $outside~x", 
    "first [abc] middle [xyz] last", 
    $m);
print_r($m);
```

or less verbose

```
  preg_match_all("~\[.+?\]|[^\[\]]+~", $str, $matches)
```

Answer (score 2):

As every one says that you should use preg_split, but only one person replied with an expression that meets your needs, <strike>and i think that is a little complex</strike> - not complex, a little to verbose but he has updated his answer to counter that.

This expression is what most of the replies have stated.

```
/\[.*?\]/
```

But that only prints out

```
Array
(
    [0] => first 
    [1] =>  middle 
    [2] =>  last
)
```

and you stated you wanted whats inside and outside the braces, sio an update would be:

```
/[\[.*?\]]/
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first 
    [1] => abc
    [2] =>  middle 
    [3] => xyz
    [4] =>  last
)
```

but as  you can see that its capturing white spaces as well, so lets go a step further and get rid of those:

```
/[\s]*[\[.*?\]][\s]*/
```

This will give you a desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => abc
    [2] => middle
    [3] => xyz
    [4] => last
)
```

This i think is the expression your looking for.

[Here is a LIVE Demonstration of the above Regex](http://codepad.org/UTDA5Nrg)